How to connect two circles by shortest distance in Metapost?/
Suppose I have two circles in Metapost, which is trivial to create. Now I want to connect them by the shortest distance between their perimeters. How can I do this?
I know I have not provided MWE but it is really trivial. Thanks a lot in advance.

The OP is correct that the shortest connection between two non-overlapping circles will be the line between their centres, but MP provides two useful macros called cutbefore and cutafter to save you doing the calculations.
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document} 
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

  z1 = (+30, 42 normaldeviate);
  z2 = (-30, 42 normaldeviate);

  path C[];
  C1 = fullcircle scaled 50 shifted z1;
  C2 = fullcircle scaled 40 shifted z2;

  path connection; 
  connection = z1 -- z2 cutbefore C1 cutafter C2;

  draw connection withcolor red;
  draw C1;
  draw C2;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

compile this with lualatex to produce a PDF that looks like this:

(although the circles will be in different random positions each time you compile).

Thanks a lot. I have decided to use Asymptote for future drawings because the language is much more natural.

Good luck with that...

It dawned upon me that I can find the equation of the two circles connecting the centers. Then find the point of intersection of this line with two circles and join those points.
So in context what we can do is following:
\starttext
\startMPcode
draw fullcircle scaled 1cm;
draw fullcircle scaled 1cm shifted (3cm, 4.5cm);
path p;
p = (0, 0) .. (3cm, 4.5cm);
pair a;
a = point 0.5cm on p;
drawdot a withcolor red;
dotlabel.lrt("$v$", a);
\stopMPcode
\stoptext

The point a will be on circumference of first circle. Similarly, we can find another point b on circumference of second circle and join them.

That's what I was about to tell you. I don't remember much metapost, but I think you can also do this and avoid intersections (like tikz): If A and B are the centers and a and b are the radius then a point is the A!a!B (That is, the point on segment AB that is a distance a from A) and the another Is B!b!A.

Note that point a on p is a extra macro in Context / Metafun.  The plain MP equivalent is point arctime a of p of p.

Yes, I am aware of it.
